# FiddlerCore .Net set timeout for the request

Tags: .net, debugging, http-proxy, fiddlercore

I need to setup timeout for the request to 1 or 2 minutes. It will be better if I can do it for specific requests and for specific timeout in the BeforeRequest event. What I need is to when timeout expires decide if I should cancel request or not. The worst case scenario is to setup just to 3-5 minutes, if I can't on the fly decide should I abort request or not.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you need to "decide" whether the request is cancelled or not, the right approach is to have a timer that's *outside* of all of FiddlerCore's logic. But it would be best to step back a bit and explain at a higher level what you hope to accomplish with all of this.

Comment: I use Selenium and Chrome. Some requests may not complete(Chrome waiting indefinitely for some request to complete) as result everything hangs. I receive timeout exception after 1 minute, but the WebDriver object is getting unmanageable. To make WebDriver work you need press cancel button in Chrome. Chrome doesn't have a timeout option. To Solve that issue I found .Net proxy implementation which I configured to work with 1 minute timeout.

Comment: After timeout expires I just interrupt connection in a proxy & Chrome gets an error but WebDriver is in a working condition and I can retry. The implementation I found it is poorly implemented, doesn't work properly with https and no keep-alive. What I need is if request is not completed after 1 minute:

check the full url and decide if I need to wait or cancel with any error to stop Chrome waiting for request to Complete.